# Passing StringBuilder to PInvoke function

Tags: c#, string, marshalling

In one of the post Titled "Call a c++ method that returns a string, from c#"

Its said that , to make the following Pinvoke to work  change the C++ signature to as

```
extern "C" REGISTRATION_API void calculate(LPSTR msg)
```

### C++ code

```
extern "C" REGISTRATION_API void calculate(char* msg)
```

### C# code

```
[DllImport("thecpp.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)] 
static extern void calculate(StringBuilder sMsg);
```

How can stringBuilder which is a class ,convertd to long ptr to string .(but this is the accepted answer)

Shouldnt we use use IntPtr as below ?

```
extern "C" REGISTRATION_API void calculate(Intptr msg)
```

Answer (score 9):

Look for the section marked "Passing Strings", the marshaler has got some added smarts to do this trick.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx](http://web.archive.org/web/20170804060344/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx)

> To solve this problem (since many of
>   the Win32 APIs expect string buffers)
>   in the full .NET Framework, you can,
>   instead, pass a
>   System.Text.StringBuilder object; a
>   pointer will be passed by the
>   marshaler into the unmanaged function
>   that can be manipulated. The only
>   caveat is that the StringBuilder must
>   be allocated enough space for the
>   return value, or the text will
>   overflow, causing an exception to be
>   thrown by P/Invoke.

Comment: That link goes to the .NET **Compact** Framework. Does it also apply to the .NET Framework, and is there a documentation as well?

Comment: I believe it does - I have written code that uses this & doesn't run on the Compact framework.  Did you give it a try ? The last section on this page also confirms this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I did try, but (as I later found out) with a function that is special in that it allocates the memory and expects the caller to free it, `FindMimeFromData`. This doesn't seem to work with StringBuilder, I only got garbage as a result.

Comment: @ygoe Is the native function allocating a string? The functions i called had corresponding freeXXX functions (that deallocated the native memory allocated) that had to be called for cleanup.

Comment: Yes it is, but the docs say I have to call some generic FreeXXX method to free the memory, and so do all the samples I could find. Works well.