# How to call C function in DLL from C#?

Tags: c#, c, dll, pinvoke

I need to call the following function of C by importing DLL in C# but it gives the following error.

I have imported the DLL and successfully executed other functions while this function throws error.

**C Method:**

```cpp
long __stdcall VBVMR_Input_GetDeviceDescA(long zindex, long * nType, char * szDeviceName, char * szHardwareId);
```

**C# Code:**

```cs
[DllImport("VoicemeeterRemote.dll", EntryPoint = "VBVMR_Input_GetDeviceDescA", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern int VBVMR_Input_GetDeviceDescA(long zindex, ref long nType, [Out] byte[] szDeviceName, [Out] byte[] szHardwareId);

long nType = 0;
byte[] c = new byte[100];
byte[] b = new byte[100];
long i=0;

int rep = VBVMR_Input_GetDeviceDescA(i,ref nType, c, b);
```

It throws exception on executing `VBVMR_Input_GetDeviceDescA` as:

> A call to PInvoke function `'Voicemeter!Voicemeter.Program::VBVMR_Input_GetDeviceDescA'` has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be `__cdecl`, not `__stdcall`?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/cdecl?view=vs-2017

Comment: It is __stdcall in dll. I have used the following for import.

[DllImport("VoicemeeterRemote.dll", EntryPoint = "VBVMR_Input_GetDeviceDescA", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]

Comment: You have `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl` in the question. Apart from that, C's `long` is C#'s `int`. On top of that, you should use `CharSet.Ansi` [and `StringBuilder`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3203005/11683) for the `char * szDeviceName, char * szHardwareId`.

Comment: same response on changing it to CallingConvention.StdCall

Comment: @UmairAsghar Address the other two issues.

Comment: Problem solved by changing long to int and setting CallConvention to CallingConvention.StdCall.

private static extern int VBVMR_Input_GetDeviceDescA(int zindex, ref int nType, [Out] byte[] szDeviceName, [Out] byte[] szHardwareId);

Thank you all for your support

Answer (score 1):

If your exported function is declared with the calling convention `__stdcall` in the DLL that exports it, you need to import it in your C# code with `CallingConvention.StdCall`, not `Cdecl`.

The reason that this calling convention mismatch exhibits an error about "unbalancing the stack" is because after a call to a `cdecl` function, the calling code is expected to adjust the stack pointer register after the function call to remove the parameters passed to the function from the stack. However, since your function is actually an `stdcall` function, it does that itself in the `ret imm16` instruction it uses, so your stack underflows when the calling code "cleans up the stack"  too.

The next problem is that `long` in C# and `long` in MSVC are different sizes, so even with the `stdcall` calling convention, the called function pops the number of bytes corresponding to what it thinks is the correct size for the parameter list, but since C#'s `long` is not the same size as MSVC's `long`, the stack is still unbalanced after the `ret imm16` instruction at the end of the DLL function. C#'s `int` type corresponds to a `long`, however.